# use of wait-notify, whats wrong in my approach

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I am trying to implement a case of shared variable like semaphores. In that I have 3 thread which should be run sequentially. below is my program. Could u tell me where I am wrong?

```
class Test2{    
    private volatile static int sharedvarNEXT = 1;
    public synchronized static int getSharedvarNEXT(){
        return sharedvarNEXT;   
    }
    public synchronized static void setSharedvarNEXT(int val){
        sharedvarNEXT = val;    
    }
    public static void main(String[] s){
        new classACaps().start();
        new classAsmall().start();
        new class1().start();
    }
}

class classACaps extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try{
            for(char c='A';c<='Z';c++){
                if(Test2.getSharedvarNEXT() == 1){
                    System.out.println(c);
                    Test2.setSharedvarNEXT(2);
                    notify();
                } else {
                    wait();
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("caught in A");      
        }
    }
}

class classAsmall extends Thread{  
    public void run(){
        try{
            for(char c='a';c<='z';c++){
                if(Test2.getSharedvarNEXT() == 2){
                    System.out.println(c);      
                    Test2.setSharedvarNEXT(3);
                    notify();
                } else {
                    wait();
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("caught in a");      
        }
    }
}

class class1 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try{
            for(int c=1;c<=26;c++){
                if(Test2.getSharedvarNEXT() == 3){
                    System.out.println(c);
                    Test2.setSharedvarNEXT(1);
                    notify();
                }else {
                    wait();
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("caught in 1");      
        }
    }
}
```

> expected outcome is like : A, a, 1, B, b, 2......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In that I have 3 thread which should be run sequentially.

Well you're *not* running sequentially - you're running the three concurrently, which is the nature of what happens when you start three separate threads.

Those threads aren't synchronizing against each other *at all*. It doesn't really sound like you should have three threads at all, given your requirements.

Additionally:

- You don't have any `synchronized` blocks; both `wait()` and `notify()` can *only* be called by a thread which owns the monitor on which they're called
- Using `wait()` and `notify()` on instances of `Thread` is strongly discouraged, as the internals of `Thread` use it themselves. I suggest you create a separate object *just* to synchronize/wait/notify on.
- Your exception handling completely ignores the exception, which has been hiding the first problem from you. *Never* ignore the exception - and try to avoid catching bare `Exception` at all, in general.

Comment: yes i know these all are concurrent, i meant the outcome be sequential despite them running as separate thread. I could not completely understant point 1 & 2 could you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: do u mean one should not use wait/notify in the code which is meant to run in separate thread?

Comment: @ay89: It's not at all clear to me what you mean by "the outcome be sequential". Which part of bullets 1 & 2 did you not understand? I suggest that the *first* thing you fix is the third bullet - print out the exception, and you'll probably understand the first bullet point better...

Comment: @ay89: I mean that if you haven't synchronized on the object you're calling `wait()` or `notify()` on, you should get an exception...

Comment: @ay89 I would suggest you start with the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

Comment: @KaushikSivakumar not so sure, but a clock runs this way, all hands run concurrently yet in sequence.

Comment: @ay89: I'm not sure that using a clock as an analogy is useful, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `notify()` and `wait()` inside the `run()` method is basically calling

```
this.notify();
```

None of your `Thread`s is `synchronized` on each `this` `Thread` instance.

You cannot `notify()` if you don't own the monitor, ie. `synchronized` on it. **You're swallowing all the exceptions you get.**